# Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a calendar on my site that opens a pop-up box showing a RGB color selector. It works fine in all browsers apart from IE8. My code is below.

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

This is the error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference

Which points to this line

```
return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
```

I am not familiar with this code as it was completed by someone else at my workplace who has went on holiday for a couple of weeks. If anyone can help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

This is where the function is called. When I console.log(bgColor) in IE8 it shows up as #rgb(238, 238, 238), so i don't see why it isn't working. Maybe it is me being stupid but for life of me I cannot see it.

```
$('.period_day').click(function(e) {
    var bgColor = $(this).css('background-color');

if (rgb2hex(bgColor) == "#eeeeee") {
    $('.colour_picker').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    $('#cal_colour_val').val('#ff0000');
} else {
    $('.colour_picker').css('background-color', bgColor);
    $('#cal_colour_val').val(bgColor);
}
});
```

Comment: If `bgColor` is hex already (`#eeeeee`), it should be obvious why it doesn't work when you pass it into `rgb2hex`.

Comment: Sorry console.log(bgColor) shows up as rgb(238, 238, 238). After it has been through rgb2hex it is #eeeeee

Comment: @Pooshonk does `console.log(bgColor)` show that result *in Internet Explorer* specifically?  Different browsers report colors differently.

Comment: @Pointy it shows up exactly the same in all browsers

Comment: @Pooshonk: How can it been through `reg2hex` if that threw an exception? Please log the input `rgb` parameter and post the one that causes the error.

Comment: Finally managed to solve it, thank for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the `rgb2hex` function is being called with an argument that doesn't match the regular expression. The match failure will result in the variable `rgb` being null, and that code doesn't check for that possibility.

Thus the real problem is probably with the code that's *calling* the function.

Comment: @Pooshonk great!  It might be helpful to others in the future if you were to summarize what it is you discovered by editing your question or adding a comment.